# SQL - Average every n rows for items with same ID

Tags: sql, mariadb

I found a lot of similart posts, but any of them answered what I needed. Im trying to sumarize a big table (200M rows). What I need is to get the average every n (5 or something like that) for each ID. I've been trying with this:

```
select id, dev_id,
    row_number() over(partition by dev_id order by dev_id) as rn,
    avg(med1) over(order by dev_id rows between current row and 5 following) as avg_med1,
    avg(med2) over(order by dev_id rows between current row and 5 following) as avg_med2
from my_table;
```

What I get with that query is a moving average, however, I only want the mean of the n elements for the current id. So the output should be for ID x > avg(rows 1-5), for ID x > avg(rows 6-10), for ID y > avg(rows 11-15)...

The thing im trying to replicate is something like the following:

From:

```
dev_id, med1, med2, med3
2, 3, 4, 1
3, 2, 1, 2
3, 1, 3, 9
3, 2, 4, 7
1, 3, 3, 2
2, 4, 3, 2
1, 5, 3, 2
3, 4, 2, 3
2, 4, 7, 2
```

To:

```
dev_id, AVG(med1), AVG(med2), AVG(med3)
2, 3.5, 3.5, 1.5
3, 1.5, 2, 5.5
3, 3, 3, 5
1, 4, 3, 2
2, 4, 5, 2
```

Comment: I can't follow last table but maybe add `PARTITION BY dev_id` and use primary key for `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It doesnt work, the last table is just an average of the 3 values grouped 2 by 2. The query that is on the post returns the average on every single element, like a moving average, but I only want to display 1 every 5 values (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me, however is not what I initially planned it:

```
select id, reference, avg(b1), avg(b25), avg(b10), max(created_at)
from
(
  select id,
    @row_number := case when @reference = reference then @row_number + 1 else 0 end as row_number,
    @reference := reference as reference,
    b1, 
    b25,
    b10,
    created_at
  from history_air
  cross join (select @row_number := -1, @reference := '') as t
  order by reference, created_at
) as t
group by reference, row_number div 150
order by reference, row_number div 150;
```